# Using video stream for predictions with tensorflow js

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to take a stream from react
for example:

```
let stream="from somewhere"
videoRef.current.srcObject=stream;

<video ref={videoRef} />
```

I want to take that stream and make predictions on it using tensorflow js, and by the love of god I can't find anything on this,
I want to implement something like face-api.js, but with my own model, I want to use

`model.predict(***some tensor**+)`
so I need to take that stream to 4d tensor, how do I do that?!

and to get a predictions, but I have a stream and not an image, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you using React Native?

Comment: @yuRa I'm using react